# MultiDataTrigger Not firing once the button isEnabled property is changed from code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, xaml, multidatatrigger

I have a button which is enabled/disabled based on validation.hasError property of few textboxes and it works fine, untill i wanna disable and enable this same button from code behind based on some business logic. for example.

`if(recordExist) { btn.IsEnabled=true;} else{ btn.isenabled=false;}`

now what happens is that once the `else` logic is carried out and the button is disabled, the button is not re-enabled again even if the `validation.HasError` of all the controls return false. and like wise if the `if` logic is carried out and button is enabled it stays enabled even if the `validation.hasError` returns true. what i want is to somehow re-Trigger the `multiDataTriggers` to check the `Validation.hasError` on the `textboxes` and update the `isEnabled` property of the button accordingly. i hope i am clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Dependency Property Value Precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms743230.aspx) on MSDN.

Once you set local value, triggers can't override it. You need to adjust bindings, triggers etc. to take the logic in the code behind into account. If you're using MVVM (and you should), you can add the condition to your view-model.

Alternatively, if you want the control to forget about the local value and let the trigger take precedence, you can use `ClearValue`. Or you can use `SetCurrentValue` and avoid giving precedence to the new value. However, you should avoid using these functions, they will make your code harder to understand and maintain.

Comment: I think it would be useful to add that one can actually set value of a dependency property and maintain it's current data source (binding etc.) - by using `SetCurrentValue` method. In OP's case that can be achieved by calling `btn.SetCurrentValue(Button.IsEnabledProperty, true /*or false*/)`.

Comment: @Grx70 You're correct. Updated my answer. However, I think `ClearValue`, `SetCurrentValue` etc. should never be used to handle logic like this. It looks like a hack. There're good uses for these functions, but this is not the case.

Comment: Thanks for the Response Guys, but as i mentioned above i am using `style.triggers` and `MultiDataTrigger` to handle the enabling and disabling of the button and `Isenabled` property is not set inside Button Tag in xaml. and i tried `setCurrentValue` it does not work at all and it does not change the property. and I did not quite get the `ClearValue` option can you please provide an example.

Comment: @FaisalMalikyar Don't use these functions. Just create a property `IsButtonFooEnabled` in your view-model and bind to it. Don't use code-behind just to enable and disable controls, it's fragile and unmaintainable.

Comment: @Discord I am using ValidationRules for validation, so can you please provide an example of the property `IsButtonFooEnabled` where should i put it and how do i bind it to the buttons isEnabled property.?

Comment: By the way +1 for the `ClearValue` option it did what i was looking for. but still if there are better practices i am open to suggestions. thanks

Comment: @FaisalMalikyar I'm confused about what condition should take precedence, but depending on your requirements you can put logic "if (record exists) enable else disable" either into binding (`IsEnabled={Binding IsRecordExists}`) or into a trigger (`<DataTrigger IsRecordExists=False><Setter IsEnabled=False></>`). With triggers, it's easy to control precedence (the latest trigger wins).